# Delphi VCL: Form elements undeclared on custom procedure/function

Tags: delphi, vcl

I've got this:

```
procedure Welcome(user: string; accesslevel: integer);
begin
   if accesslevel>= 10  then btCustomers.Text = 'Customer overview';
end;
```

Though, while the button exists on the form, btCustomers is declared an 'undeclared identifier'. What am I missing?

*P.S. I am aware that this should be handled by the form OnCreate, but the Welcome procedure gets called from an external form.*

Comment: Why are you using a procedure that is NOT a member of any class?  `procedure TMyForm.Welcome` would have access to `btCustomers` if `btCustomers` is a member of `TMyForm`.  Object Oriented Programming = Good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could to pass a reference to the form so that the button can in turn be referenced.

```
procedure Welcome(form: TMyForm; user: string; accesslevel: integer);
begin
   if accesslevel>= 10  then form.btCustomers.Text = 'Customer overview';
end;
```

However, any time you have a global scope function that takes as its first parameter a reference to an object, you have a candidate for a method of that object. So, add a method to `TMyForm`.

```
procedure TMyForm.Welcome(user: string; accesslevel: integer);
begin
   if accesslevel>= 10  then btCustomers.Text = 'Customer overview';
end;
```

And call it like this:

```
MyForm.Welcome(user, accesslevel);
```

Comment: If you use the function globally, then I would have it return the new string as output instead of updating the Button directly.  The calling Form can then decide what to do with that output when the function exits, such as update its local Button.  That way, the function becomes less likely to fail and becomes ignorant of how its being used so it can be reused for other purposes if desired.